# Numpy matrix multiplication with str and negativ int

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

After measuring a structure's vibration with accelerometers I get a csv with time and data sets including my values for acceleration for each sensor coordinate direction. In the future I will be using around 100 sensors with local CS's differing from the global CS. Therefore I would like to use a single transformation matrix to plot each acceleration for each direction.

An Input file could look like this:

```
time;loc1_x;loc1_y;loc1_z
0;0.0068;0.0419;0.0107
0.00042;0.0083;0.042;0.021
0.00083;0.0083;0.045;0.009
```

So if I want to plot the global z accelerations my `plt.plot` expression needs to plot all values from `loc1_y` multiplied by -1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt(filepath+'\\'+filename, delimiter=';', skip_header=0,
                     names=['time', 'loc1_x', 'loc1_y', 'loc1_z'])

loc_sens = np.array(['loc1_x', 'loc1_y', 'loc1_z'])
trans = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, -1, 0]])

glo_sens = np.dot(loc_sens, trans)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(data['time'], glo_sens[i], color='xcolor', label='xlabel')
```

In this example my data sets are callable by string expressions like 'loc1_x' and have been put together in an array called loc_sens. Because I need to plot negative values of 'loc1_y' I want to use a transformation matrix which gives me an array looking like:

```
glo_sens = ['loc1_x', 'loc1_z', '-loc1_y']
```

The problem is strings can't be multiplied by negative scalars as far as I know. I would appreciate any help or easier ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I hope that helps now

Comment: You want a matrix, right? Can you post your complete expected output? Are you looking for `np.char.add(np.where(trans < 0, '-', ''), loc_sens)`?

Comment: thats already pretty helpfull! The idea was to use a transformation matrix consisting of only 0's and +/-1's to transform this `loc_sens = ['loc1_x', 'loc1_y', 'loc1_z']` to that `glo_sens = ['loc1_x', loc1_z', '-loc1_y']`. The idea was not only changing +/- sign but also the elements position inside the array.

Comment: Can you explain when/why the swap occurs? Your problem isn't as simple as made out to be, and it isn't clear what you want because you didn't post your complete expected output, nor did you explain when and why the swapping is done.

Comment: If I want to plot my sensors local z coordinate I use `plt.plot(data['time'], data['loc1_z'])` but actually it has a different orientation compared to my global coordinates so I need to use `plt.plot(data['time'], data['-loc1_y'])` to have the right result. My input is `loc_sens` containing my sensor coordinates and `trans` which I have to define manually. My Intention is to use a simple matrix multiplication to manipulate the sign and position of `loc_sens` elements. `loc_sens * trans = glo_sens`. Does this explanation help?

Comment: `''loc1_x'` is just a string.  It isn't a variable or data.  `data['loc1_x']` is a field of the data array, and thus a 1d array of floats.

Comment: I am aware of that. I would just have to define a variabel for each data array. My only intention is to rearange the elements inside an array by using a Matrix. Actually its simple math like multiplying vector1 = (a,b,c) by matrix trans which should give me vector2 = (a,c,-b). I just don't know how to do that in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your `data` array:

```
In [97]: txt = """time;loc1_x;loc1_y;loc1_z
    ...: 0;0.0068;0.0419;0.0107
    ...: 0.00042;0.0083;0.042;0.021
    ...: 0.00083;0.0083;0.045;0.009""".splitlines()
In [98]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=';', dtype=None, names=True)
In [99]: data
Out[99]: 
array([(0.     , 0.0068, 0.0419, 0.0107),
       (0.00042, 0.0083, 0.042 , 0.021 ),
       (0.00083, 0.0083, 0.045 , 0.009 )],
      dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('loc1_x', '<f8'), ('loc1_y', '<f8'), ('loc1_z', '<f8')])
```

Accessing fields by name

```
In [100]: data['time']
Out[100]: array([0.     , 0.00042, 0.00083])
In [101]: data['loc1_x']
Out[101]: array([0.0068, 0.0083, 0.0083])
```

A string is just a string:

```
In [102]: 'loc1_x'
Out[102]: 'loc1_x'
In [103]: loc_sens = np.array(['loc1_x', 'loc1_y', 'loc1_z'])
     ...: trans = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, -1, 0]])
     ...:
```

An array of strings is just an array of strings

```
In [104]: loc_sens
Out[104]: array(['loc1_x', 'loc1_y', 'loc1_z'], dtype='<U6')
```

It doesn't make much sense to `dot` on strings

```
In [105]: np.dot(loc_sens, trans)
...
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

Python does define multiplication for strings, but I don't think that's what you want:

```
In [106]: [str*n for n, str in zip([1,2,3],loc_sens)]
Out[106]: ['loc1_x', 'loc1_yloc1_y', 'loc1_zloc1_zloc1_z']
```

What I suspect you want is 3 of the columns of `data` as 3x3 matrix.

```
In [107]: locs = np.stack((data['loc1_x'], data['loc1_y'], data['loc1_z']))
In [108]: locs
Out[108]: 
array([[0.0068, 0.0083, 0.0083],
       [0.0419, 0.042 , 0.045 ],
       [0.0107, 0.021 , 0.009 ]])
In [109]: np.dot(locs, trans)
Out[109]: 
array([[ 0.0068, -0.0083,  0.0083],
       [ 0.0419, -0.045 ,  0.042 ],
       [ 0.0107, -0.009 ,  0.021 ]])
```

Or maybe you want to use `locs.T` (transpose).

Converting several fields of a structured array into a 2d array is a little tricky.  Plus there have been changes in how multiple fields can accessed (in v 1.14).  So I choose the safest - stacking (concatenate as columns) of the individual fields.

---

From comments and code it sounds like you think that the fields of `data` can be referenced simply by the string. Or that the string is a variable name or something like that.  Yes, you use the strings a field index, much like you would use strings as keys of a dictionary.

---

If I load the data as floats, I can access columns by slice

```
In [112]: data1 = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=';', dtype=float, skip_header=1)
In [113]: data1
Out[113]: 
array([[0.     , 0.0068 , 0.0419 , 0.0107 ],
       [0.00042, 0.0083 , 0.042  , 0.021  ],
       [0.00083, 0.0083 , 0.045  , 0.009  ]])
In [114]: np.dot(data1[:,1:], trans)
Out[114]: 
array([[ 0.0068, -0.0107,  0.0419],
       [ 0.0083, -0.021 ,  0.042 ],
       [ 0.0083, -0.009 ,  0.045 ]])
In [115]: np.dot(data1[:,1:].T, trans)
Out[115]: 
array([[ 0.0068, -0.0083,  0.0083],
       [ 0.0419, -0.045 ,  0.042 ],
       [ 0.0107, -0.009 ,  0.021 ]])
```

Or with a fancier dtype

```
In [118]: data2 = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=';', dtype=[('time','f8'),('loc1'
     ...: ,'f8',(3,))], skip_header=1)
In [119]: data2
Out[119]: 
array([(0.     , [0.0068, 0.0419, 0.0107]),
       (0.00042, [0.0083, 0.042 , 0.021 ]),
       (0.00083, [0.0083, 0.045 , 0.009 ])],
      dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('loc1', '<f8', (3,))])
In [121]: data2['loc1']
Out[121]: 
array([[0.0068, 0.0419, 0.0107],
       [0.0083, 0.042 , 0.021 ],
       [0.0083, 0.045 , 0.009 ]])
```

---

We can use the list of strings to access several fields of the structured array:

```
In [128]: data[loc_sens]
Out[128]: 
array([(0.0068, 0.0419, 0.0107), (0.0083, 0.042 , 0.021 ),
       (0.0083, 0.045 , 0.009 )],
      dtype={'names':['loc1_x','loc1_y','loc1_z'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[8,16,24], 'itemsize':32})
```

They've made some changes in how this multifield index works in v 1.14, and I'm still trying to understand it.  `view` and `astype` aren't working.  `tolist` is the old fallback method for converting to/from structured arrays:

```
In [137]: data[loc_sens].tolist()
Out[137]: [(0.0068, 0.0419, 0.0107), (0.0083, 0.042, 0.021), (0.0083, 0.045, 0.009)]
In [138]: np.array(data[loc_sens].tolist())
Out[138]: 
array([[0.0068, 0.0419, 0.0107],
       [0.0083, 0.042 , 0.021 ],
       [0.0083, 0.045 , 0.009 ]])
```

Comment: that's a great explanation! thanks! What I learned now is that making my arrays accessible makes life a lot easier. But when I want to work with all of my `data` I would end up with a 3000x15 matrix. Is there a way to multiply whole columns by a scalar and change the columns position by defining each column as a separate array? `matrix = [column1, column2,...]` , `column1 = [elem1, elem2,...]` and get like `matrix = [column2, column1,...]` with `column1 = [-elem1, -elem2,...]`